# regex stl ECMAScript extremly slow

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group

I had a question, I'm using std::regex with these params :

```
const std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type grammar = std::regex_constants::ECMAScript;

    const std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type optionNonICase =
            grammar | std::regex_constants::optimize;

    const std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type optionICase =
            std::regex_constants::icase | grammar |
            std::regex_constants::optimize;
```

I'm parsing a big file **line by line** (lines are not very big) and extract some data.

I noticed that exact same code with `java.util.regex` is much faster that `std::regex`...

Do someone know how to opmtimize regex with STL with ECMA ?
Maybe I need to translate to an other grammar like grep, awk ?
Otherwise, maybe there is an alternative library to use in c++ ?

Thanks for help

Comment: `<regex>` isn't anything to do with the `STL` which only describes the *containers* and *algorithms* parts of the Standard Library.

Comment: If I need faster regex I use `PCRE`.

Comment: @Galik -- unfortunately, "STL" has come to mean STandard Library. Despite being a curmudgeon I've given up on fixing that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, not according to every `C++` reference book I have ever seen. The term refers to a container and algorithms library that is particularly important to computer science and teaching. Therefore, it needs its own name. For that reason I continue to correct people when they get it wrong.

Comment: @Galik thanks for your clarification. PCRE exists in Java or C++ ?

Comment: @X6Entrepreneur [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/) is a `C` library, so it works fine with `C++`,  but it probably has bindings for other languages too.

Comment: @Galik thanks a lot, will take a look. Do you know what's using java.util.regex as grammar ? Because they have a quite good performance, maybe they are using pcre ? It's not possible to use PCRE syntax with STL ?

Comment: An instance of the Pattern class represents a regular expression that is specified in string form in a syntax similar to that used by Perl. (from Pattern Java documentation)

Comment: maybe try `Boost.Regex`

Comment: Need documentation on how to build boost for Android with NDK and use it within JNI... Do you have one?

Answer (score 0):

After some research and some tests, I found that Boost.Regex is way better and way faster than STL Regex. (Like 100x more)

Thanks to this repo : `https://github.com/PurpleI2P/Boost-for-Android-Prebuilt` I was able to integrate boost quickly and use it on android app with JNI project